# How can I show the 'No Books Found' row if null value is returned in filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I am trying to show a 'No Books Found!' row if angular filter returns no result in AngularJs.

But I cannot somehow make it to work. Here is my html code:

```html
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type='text' ng-model='search' class='form-control' aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row' id='search-table'> 
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-collapse' ng-init="books = [{ 
                                title  : 'The Life-Changing Magic of Tidying Up: The Japanese Art of Decluttering and Organizing', 
                                author : 'Marie Kondo', 
                                price  : '9.68' 
                            },
                            { 
                                title  : 'Quieting Your Heart: 6-Month Bible-Study Journal', 
                                author : 'Darlene Schacht', 
                                price  : '7.14' 
                            },
                            { 
                                title  : 'First 100 Words', 
                                author : 'Roger Priddy', 
                                price  : '3.19' 
                            }]">
                            <thead>
                                <th> TITLE </th>
                                <th> AUTHOR </th>
                                <th> PRICE </th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter:search">
                                    <td> {{ book.title }}  </td>
                                    <td> {{ book.author }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ book.price }}  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class='info' ng-show="!books.length">
                                    <td colspan=3> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign  '></i> No Books Found </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RayonDabre Still not working.

Comment: if angular returns null then just specify ng-if="!books"

Comment: @DennisNerush I did this '<tr class="info" ng-if="!books">' But still no luck!

Comment: It seems that you init the books array using ng-init before your ng-repeat. There is no way that books will be empty.

Comment: @DennisNerush I tried removing the ng-init and moving the books declaration in an external JS file. And including the JS file at the bottom. But still the same result.

Comment: Do you still init the array somewhere?

Comment: @DennisNerush Yeah! I got $scope.books having the books value.

Comment: Well if the books array has value then you won't see the "no books found" row. You should look in your project where do ou automaticly init it.Try to set the array to empty or undefined and then see if the row is displayed.

Comment: @DennisNerush The answer of rayon worked for me though! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `(books|filter:search).length` as `books.length` will always return length of the `base` array which is not being affected by `filter`

`(books|filter:search).length` will return the `length` of the array after applying filter.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/g1mxL8qt/1/)

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Your answer worked like a charm. Thank you for your work explanation.

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__